# Why does "man x-terminal-emulator" return the output of "man gnome-terminal"?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, manpage

I know what `x-terminal-emulator` is and does, but I don't understand why there isn't exist a special manual page for it instead to be redirected to the manual page of `gnome-terminal`. I would like to see a manual page explaining what `x-terminal-emulator` exactly does and in that page a reference to `man gnome-terminal`.

Is this correct (if yes, then why, for example, the output of `man dir` doesn't return the output of `man ls`)? It is there a good motivation behind this fact?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`x-terminal-emulator` is a [virtual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-binary.html#s-virtual_pkg) [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/x-terminal-emulator). The terminal emulator is configured by Debian's [alternative system](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives).

On Ubuntu you can easily follow this symlink construction, e.g. for gnome-terminal:

```
$ which x-terminal-emulator
/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
$ ls -lF /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
/usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator -> /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator*
$ ls -al /etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator
/etc/alternatives/x-terminal-emulator -> /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper*
```

Now regarding the man pages, `update-alternatives` also links the man page of `gnome-terminal` to `x-terminal-emulator` as explained in the [`update-alternatives`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/en/man1/update-alternatives.1.html) manual:

> ```
>    It is often useful for a number of alternatives to be synchronized,  so
>    that they are changed as a group; for example, when several versions of
>    the  vi(1)  editor  are  installed,  the   man   page   referenced   by
>    /usr/share/man/man1/vi.1 should correspond to the executable referenced
>    by /usr/bin/vi.  update-alternatives handles this by  means  of  master
>    and  slave links; when the master is changed, any associated slaves are
>    changed too.  A master link and its associated slaves make  up  a  link
>    group.
> ```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/32550)

Comment: You might want to explicitly replace ``ll`` with ``ls -lF`` for the benefit of people who don’t have the “standard” aliases.  And why not use the same command on the second and third lines? Also, you should probably link to the man page you’re quoting (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/update-alternatives.1.html).

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' good idea, thx.

Answer (score 0):

You could run in bash, to follow the link:

```
$ readlink -f $(command -v x-terminal-emulator)
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
```

and/or:

```
$ update-alternatives --display x-terminal-emulator
x-terminal-emulator - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper - priority 40
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/gnome-terminal.1.gz
/usr/bin/lxterm - priority 30
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/lxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/uxterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/uxterm.1.gz
/usr/bin/xterm - priority 20
  slave x-terminal-emulator.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/xterm.1.gz
Current 'best' version is '/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper'.
```

Notice: the man page is also linked to `gnome-terminal.1.gz`.